# How can I run a script before Deja-dup back up starts?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I have set up a perforce server and now want to run `deja-dup` back up to back the server up.

The problem is that before the back up starts, I have to run a script to make a check point on perforce database and journaling.

The question is: can I change deja-dup setting to run that script before the back up starts or there is another better automated way to do that?

Please let me know if further info is required. I have  Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 1):

> The question is: can I change deja-dup setting to run that script before the back up starts

Nope. deja-dup is made to do 1 thing and do it good: make a backup. It has, intentionally, not got a lot of features.

> or there is another better automated way to do that?

Create a script that does the things you need it to do and let the script itself start deja-dup and then execute your script instead of the deja-dup executable.

Comment: Now I wonder, how would you do that?

Comment: He already has a script so in that case you add dejadup to that script.

Comment: And the details are? `deja-dup --backup` ;-) ... how do you get it to do it daily?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do what you want, to my knowledge.  You could have something server-side that notices new files in the backup directory?

Comment: there are two open bugs in launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/838654, https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/889416) which support this claim. So unfortunately it seems this is currently not possible - even though the developers like the idea (it's just not on their TODO list currently).